# How to align cascaded div containers with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the following layout for a navigation bar with Flexbox. I am stuck with the alignment of the divs. This is how it should like:

[image: Sample DIV Layout]

This is what i build up with Divs and CSS. But i dont know how to align those divs, so that i get the desired result.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht7p4d0t/1/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  heigth: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="logo">
    100x100px Logo
  </div>
  <div id="left_side">
    <div id="top_nav">
      <div id="title">TITLE OF PAGE</div>
      <div id="menu_swith">SWITCH</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_nav">
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 1</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 2</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 3</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a few more flex containers to some of the child divs. I'd also specify the width and flex-direction on the `#left_side` div and justify the content on the `#top_nav` div.

Try the snippet below or see this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ht7p4d0t/2/):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav,
#left_side,
#top_nav,
#bottom_nav {
  display: flex;
}

#left_side {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

#top_nav {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  heigth: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="logo">
    100x100px Logo
  </div>
  <div id="left_side">
    <div id="top_nav">
      <div id="title">TITLE OF PAGE</div>
      <div id="menu_swith">SWITCH</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_nav">
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 1</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 2</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 3</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many good guides to flexbox available. This one is very good: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Your layout can be achieved by adding the following CSS

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8bw3az8/1/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

#left_side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

#top_nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
}

#bottom_nav {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="logo">
    100x100px Logo
  </div>
  <div id="left_side">
    <div id="top_nav">
      <div id="title">TITLE OF PAGE</div>
      <div id="menu_swith">SWITCH</div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_nav">
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 1</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 2</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 3</div>
      <div class="nav_item">Menu 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is one way to build the layout. You'll need extra containers to make it work.

However, if you want to keep it really simple, use CSS Grid:

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
  grid-template-areas: " logo title switch " 
                       " logo  nav   nav   ";
}

#logo        { grid-area: logo; }
#title       { grid-area: title; }
#menu_switch { grid-area: switch; }
nav          { grid-area: nav; display: flex; }

nav > a {
  flex: 0 0 75px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

/* for demo only */
#logo        { background-color: lightgray; }
#title       { background-color: pink; }
#menu_switch { background-color: skyblue; }
nav          { background-color: lightgreen; }
*            { box-sizing: border-box; }
div, a       { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;
               text-align: center; }
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">100x100px<br>Logo</div>
  <div id="title">Page Title</div>
  <div id="menu_switch">Switch</div>
  <nav>
    <a class="nav_item">Menu 1</a>
    <a class="nav_item">Menu 2</a>
    <a class="nav_item">Menu 3</a>
    <a class="nav_item">Menu 4</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ht7p4d0t/3/)

For an explanation of the grid rules above and browser support data, see these posts:

- [CSS-only masonry layout but with elements ordered horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276)
- [Browser support for CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46059956/3597276)