# GRID items right aligned

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm playing with "grid layout" and I have a "section" with 100% width. This is display: grid.

Inside it there are 4 other divs that I would like to appear on the right side instead of the left side.

Here is my code:

```css
.fullWidth {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "it01 it02 it03 it04 it05";
  grid-template-rows: 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 200px 40px;
  background: orange;
}

.item01 {
  grid-area: it01;
  background: lime;
}

.item02 {
  grid-area: it02;
  background: blue;
}

.item03 {
  grid-area: it03;
  background: red;
}

.item04 {
  grid-area: it04;
  background: yellow;
}

.item05 {
  grid-area: it05;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<section class="fullWidth">
  <div class="item01"> </div>
  <div class="item02"> </div>
  <div class="item03"> </div>
  <div class="item04"> </div>
  <div class="item05"> </div>
</section>
```

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2mpsuc7c/

Comment: You could always flip your monitor 180 degrees. If that doesn't have the desired result add: `align-items: end;` to `.fullwidth`

Comment: I tried to set align-items: end; in the fiddle example.. The content disapeared!

Comment: Then what about `justify-items: end;` It aligns the content to the right side of the box in order.

Comment: Unfortunatelly they also disappear!

Comment: Works for [me](https://imgur.com/a/vEosW) but then again grid is still not supported on [every browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid). This includes safari that does not support `grid-template-rows`

Comment: [Browser support for CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060829/3597276)

Comment: @Michael_B Look at the known issues, there is one that specifically targets Safari. The fact that it disappears on his screen and not on the screenshot I showed should say enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
.fullWidth {
    justify-content: end;
}
```

Updated snippet:

```css
.fullWidth {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "it01 it02 it03 it04 it05";
  grid-template-rows: 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 200px 40px;
  background: orange;
  justify-content: end;
}

.item01 {
  grid-area: it01;
  background: lime;
}

.item02 {
  grid-area: it02;
  background: blue;
}

.item03 {
  grid-area: it03;
  background: red;
}

.item04 {
  grid-area: it04;
  background: yellow;
}

.item05 {
  grid-area: it05;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<section class="fullWidth">
  <div class="item01"> </div>
  <div class="item02"> </div>
  <div class="item03"> </div>
  <div class="item04"> </div>
  <div class="item05"> </div>
</section>
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mpsuc7c/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the **[`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)** property with `direction: rtl`:

```css
.fullWidth {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "it01 it02 it03 it04 it05";
  grid-template-rows: 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 200px 40px;
  background: orange;
  direction: rtl;
}

.item01 {
  grid-area: it01;
  background: lime;
}

.item02 {
  grid-area: it02;
  background: blue;
}

.item03 {
  grid-area: it03;
  background: red;
}

.item04 {
  grid-area: it04;
  background: yellow;
}

.item05 {
  grid-area: it05;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<section class="fullWidth">
  <div class="item01"></div>
  <div class="item02"></div>
  <div class="item03"></div>
  <div class="item04"></div>
  <div class="item05"></div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is the "mirror effect".
The item05 shows first.. 
The 4th shows second.. and so on..

Comment: You could always just restructure the elements in the DOM to reflect that :)

Comment: I get the point. But I think this is not the most semantic way to reach the goal! Thanks a lot, anyway! :)