# Edge & IE CSS Grid Compatibility

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, css-grid

I recently redeveloped my site using CSS Grid. It works on all browsers I have tried except Edge & IE where the row heights are huge. I have also tried the Autoprefixer with no luck. The display is also responsive in browsers other than Edge & IE. My CSS code is as follows and I would appreciate any suggestions:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  background: #a1dada;
  /* padding: 3rem 5rem; */
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 0.1fr);
    border-left: 10px ridge #fffb00;
    border-top: 10px ridge #fffb00;
    border-bottom: 10px ridge #fffb00;
    border-right: 10px ridge #fffb00;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;    
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    /*background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,lightblue, rgba(158, 221, 55, 0.212));*/
  }
    
  .item1 {
    grid-area: 1/2/1/5;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
   font-weight: bolder;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
    margin-top:3vh;
  }

   .item2 {
    grid-area: 2/2/2/5;
    text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: rgb(5, 83, 40);
   font-family: "Patua One";
   font-style: normal;
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1vw;
    margin: 2vh; 
  }

  .item3 {
    grid-area: 3/2/3/5;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bolder;
   color: rgb(91, 41, 226);
   font-family: "Patua One";
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: large;
   font-size: 1.75vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 2vh; 
  }

  .item4 {
    grid-area: 4/2/4/5;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 1.2vw;
   font-family: "Patua One";
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #000000;
    margin: 2vh; 
  }
  .item5 {
    grid-area: 1/1/5/2;
    background-image: url('PowerPoint Fill Shape.png');    
    width: 96%;
     
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    background-position: center;
    border-right: thick ridge rgb(240, 236, 224);
    border-width: 9px;
  }

  .services-title {
    grid-column-start: 5;
    grid-column-end: 6;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px; 
    background-color: white;
    color: #1318E7;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-left: thick ridge rgb(240, 236, 224);
    border-width: 9px;
  }

  .services-list {
    grid-column-start: 5;
    grid-column-end: 6;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 5;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25vw;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    border-left: thick ridge rgb(240, 236, 224);
    border-width: 9px;
  }

  .navmenu {
    grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-row-end: 6;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #006500;
    border: thick ridge #CC9900;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
  .navmenu > a {      
    font-family: source-sans-pro, "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif, helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    font-size:1.4vw;
 }

  .navmenu a:hover {
   color: rgb(236, 11, 11);
   font-weight: bolder;
 }

.rightmain  {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 6;
    grid-row-start: 7;
    background-color: #FFFFD6;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.center {    
    grid-area: 6/3/8/4;
    background-image: url('Patent-Img-ResG.jpg');    
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 3px;  
    background-position: top;
}

.leftmain {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 7;
    background-color: #FFFFD6;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.leftmaintitle {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 6;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFD6;
    color: #1318E7;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    margin-bottom: -1.5em;
}

.rightmaintitle {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 6;
    grid-row-start: 6;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFD6;
    color: #1318E7;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    margin-bottom: -1.5em;
}

.foot {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 7;
    align-self: end;
    background-color: #FFDAB5;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: ridge;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1.2vw;  
}
```

Comment: IE/Edge might use a different version of the spec. - https://caniuse.com/#search=css-grid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060829/3597276

Comment: It should work with MS Edge. IE 11 use the older version of Grid. So the new version of grid will not work with IE. While you post the code you also need to post the HTML along with CSS. so that we can try to run it and check the issue. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786788/css-grid-layout-not-working-in-edge-and-ie-11-even-with-ms-prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Edge does not recognize "fr" for row height.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.